# run dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

When I run bundle I get the following error

```
~/rails_apps/redmine]# bundle
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [RedCloth-4.2.9, ZenTest-4.8.2, actionmailer-2.3.14, actionpack-2.3.14, activerecord-2.3.14, activeresource-2.3.14, activesupport-2.3.14, cgi_multipart_eof_fix-2.5.0, daemons-1.1.5, eventmachine-0.12.10, fastercsv-1.5.5, fastthread-1.0.7, ferret-0.11.8.4, gchartrb-0.8, gem_plugin-0.2.3, icalendar-1.2.0, json-1.7.5, mongrel-1.1.5, rack-1.1.3, rails-2.3.14, rake-0.9.2.2, rmagick-2.13.1, rubygems-update-1.8.15, sqlite3-1.3.5, test-spec-0.10.0, tzinfo-0.3.33] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1208:in `gem'
    from /home/jmg810/ruby/gems/bin/bundle:18
```

Here is my list of local gems, you'll notice that those gems don't match the full list of local gems

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.8)
actionpack (3.2.8)
activemodel (3.2.8)
activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.2.2)
activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter (1.2.2)
activesupport (3.2.8)
bouncy-castle-java (1.5.0146.1)
builder (3.0.3)
bundler (1.2.1)
coderay (1.0.7)
edavis10-object_daddy (0.4.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
fastercsv (1.5.5)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.1, 0.4.2)
jdbc-mysql (5.1.13)
journey (1.0.4)
jruby-openssl (0.7.7)
json (1.7.5)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.19)
multi_json (1.3.6)
mysql (2.8.1)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
net-ldap (0.3.1)
pg (0.14.1)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rmagick (2.13.1)
ruby-openid (2.2.0, 2.1.8)
sprockets (2.1.3)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.33)
```

and here is my gem env

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.15
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/jmg810/ruby/gems
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/jmg810/ruby/gems/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/jmg810/ruby/gems
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gempath" => []
     - "gem" => "--remote --gen-rdoc --run-tests"
     - "gemhome" => "/home/jmg810/ruby/gems"
     - "rdoc" => "--inline-source --line-numbers"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

I think the issue is that it is not looking in my local gems

Comment: For me, changing the GEM_PATH variable from `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448:~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global` with `$HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448:$HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global` worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in my `bash_profile` i had `$PATH:~/ruby/bin` and instead I needed `~/ruby/bin:$PATH`. It was  was using the gem in `/usr/bin` instead of `~/ruby/bin`.

Comment: I had a similar issue using rbenv and this fixed my issue. Thanks for this suggestion!

Comment: What did you do to fix it?

Comment: The first Ruby is picked up. I changed my bash profile to pick up my ruby first by prepending ruby instead of appending it.